# how to uninstall ubuntu 12.04 from virtualbox 4.3

Tags: virtualbox, uninstall

Due to some difficulties encountered in using the currently installed ubuntu, Iam trying to uninstall this ubuntu 12.04 from virtualbox 4.3. My aim is to redo the whole installation process. Iam using window 7.
I tried once by unistalling virtualbox through control panel, uninstall program. But after re installing again i find that the works done in ubuntu are still there. I wanted to start a fresh, please advice

Answer (score 1):

In the VirtualBox Manager interface, right-click on the virtual machine you want to remove and just hit `Remove...` and select `Delete all files` from the dialog.

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot for the responses, I have succeeded. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

The file that contains a certain virtual machine (like the Ubuntu machine you are trying to get rid of), are completely separate from the Virtual Box software. So you shouldn't need to uninstall/reinstall that.

Probably what is happening is that you just deleted the Virtual Machine from the virtual box interface.
To completely remove the files, go to the virtual box manager. On the left you will have listed your Ubuntu installation. Click right on that. Then click 'Remove'. Then choose the option 'Delete all files'

You probably forgot to do that last one, the previous time.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the responses I have succeeded. All the best